# Unable to add a subclass - Required arguements

Tags: java, subclass

I'm trying to extend my policy class, which takes a double value. 
I tried extending it by

```
public class DepreciablePolicy extends Policy {    

}
```

But I get an error, "Policy in class policy cannot be applied to given types; required: double, found no arguements". I was wondering how I can fix this? The extend statement was valid when I made my Policy void, but then the Policy method doesnt work if it's a void.

```
public class Policy {
   double amount;
   int policyNumber;
   public static int policyCount = 1;


   public Policy(double a){
    amount = a;
    policyNumber = policyCount;
    policyCount ++;
  }

    public boolean isExpired(){
        return false;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.print("Policy #" + this.policyNumber + " with amount $" + this.amount);
        }        
     }
```

Comment: Which line is the error message talking about?

Comment: public class DepreciablePolicy extends Policy {   
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `Policy` class doesn't have a no-args default constructor defined, You have to  explicitly make a call the super class's constructor from your `DepreciablePolicy`  constructor.

```
public class DepreciablePolicy extends Policy {    
public DepreciablePolicy(double d){
super(d)
}

}
```

Comment: Well, you don't have to declare a constructor which takes one parameter. You just have to call the superclass constructor with one argument. There's nothing dictating where that argument value comes from.

Comment: @JonSkeet Absolutely, my intention was to explicitly make a call to super-class's 1-args constructor from the sub-class.. :)

Comment: @PremGenError: Yes, and you do that - my point is that the first part of your second sentence is incorrect. You *don't* have to explicitly declare a constructor with one parameter. You have to explicitly declare a constructor, and it has to call the superclass constructor with an argument... but the number of parameters in that explicitly-declared constructor is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Policy` class *only* has a constructor which takes a `double`.

That means that every constructor in `DepreciablePolicy` needs to chain (potentially indirectly) to that constructor, e.g.

```
public DepreciablePolicy(double amount) {
    super(amount);
}
```

Of course you don't have to make your `DepreciablePolicy` constructor just take an amount as the parameter - you could add extra parameters, or even derive the superclass constructor argument from other data. For example:

```
public DepreciablePolicy(double amount, double charge) {
    super(amount + charge);
    // Now maybe use the parameters separately
}
```

Or even:

```
public DepreciablePolicy() {
    super(0); // Or some other value...
}
```

Currently you've not specified any constructor, which means the compiler is trying to create a *default* constructor for you, which would be equivalent to:

```
public DepreciablePolicy(double amount, double charge) {
    super(amount + charge);
    // Now use them separately
}
```

That's failing because there's no parameterless constructor in `Policy`.

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a class having no default or parameterless constructor, you must explicitly call the super class constructor. Else how could the `Policy.amount` field value be set?

Here you could do either

```
public class DepreciablePolicy extends Policy {    
  public DepreciablePolicy(double d) {super(d);}
}
```

or

```
public class DepreciablePolicy extends Policy {    
  public DepreciablePolicy() {super(MY_DOUBLE_CONSTANT);}
}
```

Comment: When you extend a class having no *parameterless* constructor. It can be an explicitly declared constructor, rather than a default constructor. It's the fact that it has no parameters which is the important bit.